# mount RAID disks from microsoft server 2008 on linux

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, mount

i am really sorry if there is question like this but I am literally lost.
Somebody hacked server with accountancy and i need to copy this files.

I connect this two disk to PC with linux, and I don't know how to mount them.
when I do this:

mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/    or mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/
i got this error:

mount: unknown filesystem type 'ddf_raid_member'

Do you know how to mount it?

Or there is some utility for saving data from disk?

Thank you, and sorry for this stupid question but I am new in LINUX.

Comment: Why are you trying to mount disks in an OS you are unfamiliar with?

Comment: Because someone hacked it and he wants to open them in a more "sanitary" environment, probably. More seriously though, do you know any details about this array? From the magic information, a DDF RAID is more commonly known as a "Fake raid". It would be pretty important to know what kind, or if this is something like a Windows dynamic volume RAID.